# Merging two lists with no dups

Tags: c#, list, optimization, duplicates

I need to create one list based on two other lists. But seems like it does not remove the duplicates.

Is this efficient way of merging two lists with no dupes?

```
List<String[]> blocksComparisonSet1 = new List<String[]>(); 
List<String[]> blocksComparisonSet2 = new List<String[]>(); 
//we will combine list1 and list2 into this one
List<String[]> blocksComparisonFinal = new List<String[]>(); 

//this is how I store data in each list  
//if both values found, add both of them (partial functions, FYI)
String[] NA = new String[2]; //keep results
NA[0] = baseLine; //[0] for base
NA[1] = resultLine; //[1] for result
blocksComparisonSet1.Add(NA);

//if only one value found
String[] NA = new String[2]; //keep results
NA[0] = ""; //[0] for base
NA[1] = resultLine; //[1] for result
blocksComparisonSet1.Add(NA);

//This is where I merge lists and try to remove duplicates
if (blocksComparisonSet1.Count() > 0 || blocksComparisonSet2.Count() > 0) 
//check if we have any values in out differences lists. if we do, merge them
{
    blocksComparisonFinal.AddRange(blocksComparisonSet1); 
    //add records from one list to final list
    blocksComparisonFinal.AddRange(blocksComparisonSet2); 
    //add records from second list to final list
    blocksComparisonFinal = blocksComparisonFinal.Distinct().ToList(); 
    //remove dublicates
}
```

-

```
List1[] Example    
string1 na
string2 na
string3 String1
string4 String7
string5 string8
na  string9
na  string2
```

-

```
List2[]  Example    
na  string2
na  string5
String1 string3
String7 string4
string8 string5
string9 na
string2 na
```

-

```
Final List[] must be:
na  string9
na  string2
na  string5
string1 na
String1 string3
string2 na
string3 String1
string4 String7
string5 string8
String7 string4
string8 string5
string9 na
```

Comment: Don't use `Count` when you mean `Any`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative non-Linq solution, with an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<string[]>`

```
var merged = new HashSet<string[]>(blocksComparisonSet1, new SEC());
merged.UnionWith(blocksComparisonSet2);

class SEC : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    public bool Equals(string[] p1, string[] p2){
        return p1.SequenceEqual(p2);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(string[] p){ 
        return (int)p.Sum (p1 => p1.GetHashCode()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out! There could be null `string` references in the array.

Answer (score 6):

```
var merge = blocksComparisonSet1.Union(
                blocksComparisonSet2,
                new ArrayEqualityComparer<string>()
            ).ToList();
```

You will need a custom `IEqualityComparer<string[]>`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx).

Here's one implementation:

```
class ArrayEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]> {
    public bool Equals(T[] x, T[] y) {
        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) {
            return true;
        }
        if(x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T[] x) {
        if(x == null) {
            return 0; 
        }
        return x.Aggregate(
            0,
            (h, item) => h ^ (item != null ? item.GetHashCode() : 0)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you definitely need an implementation of IEqualityComparer<string[]>.  Your code doesn't work as is stands.